# How can I open a file in a new tab with CMD + Click?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, there is the option to set workbench.editor.enablePreview to true, allowing you to open files in new tabs. However, after opening a few files, this can clutter up the tab bar, making it hard to find a particular file, eventually requiring you to close all the tabs once done. Is there a way I can configure the VSCode keyboard settings to only open files in new tabs, similar to how Chrome opens a new tab with CMD+Clicks?

Comment: `workbench.editor.enablePreview` doesn't open in a new tab for each file; it reuses the same tab *unless it's told to be kept open*... which sounds like what you want when you say things like `this can clutter up the tab bar`. So are you asking to open all files without preview functionality, in their own tab?

Comment: You can probably write a plugin yourself. Not sure if anything exists. But considering the fact, `CTRL+Click` on Windows and `CMD+Click` on Mac, will open the declaration (method/class in Java, C++, etc., and tags in XML), at least I would not like to change that behaviour.